# IE9 and "file:///" anchors

Tags: internet-explorer-9, anchor

Ok, so using an anchor with an href like "file:///C:/whatever/somefile.txt" is straightforward, until browser security gets in the way. I can get them to work with Firefox by putting settings in a user.js file, but with IE9, no matter how 'trusted' I make the site and how many things I enable, they just don't work. Nothing happens when you click on the link with href like "file:///c:/temp/list.png" or "file:///c:/", while in Firefox (and suitable settings) the file or directory are both shown successfully. In IE, using javascript and attempting 'window.location=' with that sort of href leads to an 'Access is denied' exception, while in Firefox (with suitable settings) that works fine too. Have been looking all over for information about it, but not found any. Can anyone advise on what's needed in the case of IE9?

Comment: You're trying to open this file from your site? Is the site hosted in IIS?

Comment: The site is hosted in IIS, yes. (The behaviour is the same when the site is being run from the Visual Studio 2010 developer version of IIS.) Any leads appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx to start. Then you should update your question with the exact FILE:// URI that you're using, as well as an explanation of what specifically happens when you try to use this syntax.

Comment: That article doesn't seem to apply, unfortunately, since it relates to sites that aren't in the 'trusted' zone, whereas I can't get 'file' anchors to work no matter how trusted I make the site. Just the same, I've added some example URIs to the post as requested, though in fact the behaviour is the same whatever 'file' URI is used. Any further input appreciated.